# Alert Handling + Java + webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to use switch to alert and perform an action but i face error.

Now the real issue is when i put the below code in try,catch it works perfectly. i mean it handles the alert perfectly. But when i use the same without try, catch code it throws the below exception

```
  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            String AlertText = alert.getText();
System.out.println(javascriptconfirm.getText());
            alert.accept();
```

Please find the error below

```
No alert is present (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is when you deal with alerts you have to check whether alert is present first.
I would use this approach:

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() {

  boolean presentFlag = false;

  try {

   // Check the presence of alert
   Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
   // Alert present; set the flag
   presentFlag = true;
   // if present consume the alert
   alert.accept();

  } catch (NoAlertPresentException ex) {
   // Alert not present
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  return presentFlag;

 }
```

[here](http://seleniumwebdriverfaq.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-check-presence-of-alert.html) you can get details Also do not forget about debug step by step to get to know on what step alert appears/not appears.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Correct. I used the same approach(try/catch) earlier and was able to handle it perfectly. Just wanted to know what goes wrong when u don't use a try/catch statement. I am marking this as an answer to add more meaning and to mark that this is one way of handling it. Thanks..