# How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, authentication, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popup

I'm trying to handle authentication popup using the code below:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
profile.setPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "x.x.x.x");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
baseUrl="http://" + login + ":" + password + "@" + url;
driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
```

When I execute the test, the page shows the authentication popup and still loading for a until I click cancel button. A that moment, I can access to the next page ,this mean that the authentication success but still always show the authentication popup

Comment: Check this to handle alerts/popups   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066382/alert-handling-java-webdriver

Comment: I check many alternative but it didn't work

Comment: Which alternatives, please be more specific.

Comment: I tried to authenticate using http://login:password@url with and without Firefox Profile/// Also, I tried to use ''____String window1 = driver.getWindowHandle();
     driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input")).sendKeys(login);_____''/// And i tried ti access to popup with driver.switchTo().alert()/// And any think of those work prperly // always the test stuck in loading address with popup in screen

Comment: This question should be updated to note the type of authentication pop up that is being displayed. As the marked solution does not work for the browser authentication required pop up.

Comment: Now with selenium 4, it's very easy. Please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67321556/7604647

Answer (score 40):

The Alert Method, [`authenticateUsing()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html#authenticateUsing-org.openqa.selenium.security.Credentials-) lets you skip the **Http Basic Authentication** box.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(username, password));
```

> As of **Selenium 3.4** it is still in beta
>
> Right now implementation is only done for `InternetExplorerDriver`

Comment: Cool!
Note that at this moment its still marked with the '@Beta' tag
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html#authenticateUsing(org.openqa.selenium.security.Credentials)

Comment: Hmm, in the latest chrome, it seems the basic auth login popup isnt seen as an 'alert'

Comment: @SirLenz0rlot is that still an issue in your case?

Comment: Yes, could it simply be because I'm using ChromeDriver?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be implemented in .NET :(

Comment: Is there a way to do this using Ruby?
I don't see an API that has the alertIsPresent value nor the authenticateUsing() method. Thanks :)

Comment: For anyone struggling look at :http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: What is UserAndPassword? It seems to be a class.

Comment: @RiponAlWasim UserAndPassword refers to this class - https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/security/UserAndPassword.html

Comment: OK. Thanks SurrealAnalysis

Comment: `alert.authenticateUsing` doesn't exist in .Net library

Comment: Has anybody got any good resources on how to do this with Python bindings?

Comment: Got removed https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commits/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.java

Comment: How to use this in C#? There's no method .AuthenticateUsing for Alert.

Comment: This feature has been removed in latest selenium version. However it is available in v2.53.0 as I can see.

Answer (score 36):

Don't use firefox profile and try below code:

```
driver.get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");
```

If you're implementing it in IE browser, there are certain things which you need to do.

In case your authentication server requires username with domain like "domainuser" you need to add double slash `/` to the url:

```
//localdomain\user:password@example.com
```

Comment: @Imen: try to add an `/` at the end of the url (see my answer)

Comment: You could also use- `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://UserName:Password@Example.com")`. This worked for me

Comment: so what if there is an @-sign in my password. Because there is an @-sign in my password.

Comment: @badp in this case replace @ with %40 in password only. It's url encoding.

Comment: This does not work in either a normal browser or a Selenium-powered one.

Comment: for passwords or username containing special characters like @ or : you might have to urlencode the url.  checkout https://www.urlencoder.org/

Answer (score 8):

Try following solution and let me know in case of any issues:

```
driver.get('https://example.com/')
driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("username" + Keys.TAB + "password");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

This is working fine for me

Comment: That's the one that works for me. A bit unreliable when showing the UI (probably due to how i3wm handles focus though)  but it works fine in headless.

Comment: not for me unfortunately. I get : Step failed
org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert

Answer (score 7):

I faced this issue a number of times in my application.

We can generally handle this with the below 2 approaches.

1. Pass the username and password in url itself
2. You can create an AutoIT Script and call script before opening the url.

Please check the below article in which I have mentioned both ways:
[Handle Authentication/Login window in Selenium Webdriver](http://learn-automation.com/handle-windows-authentication-using-selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: AutoIt is a primitive shame. Why does Selenium Driver not implement this important feature?

Comment: I did the exact same approach before and both works great. AutoIT is a very reliable tool if you write your commands correctly, it's very stable.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for Firefox by using [AutoAuth plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autoauth/):

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new ProfilesIni().getProfile("default");
File ffPluginAutoAuth = new File("D:\\autoauth-2.1-fx+fn.xpi");
firefoxProfile.addExtension(ffPluginAutoAuth);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Answer (score 3):

Popular solution is to append username and password in URL, like, http://username:password@website.com. However, if your username or password contains special character, then it may fail. So when you create the URL, make sure you encode those special characters.

```
String username = URLEncoder.encode(user, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
String password = URLEncoder.encode(pass, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
String url = “http://“ + username + “:” + password + “@website.com”;
driver.get(url);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Selenium 4** supports authenticating using Basic and Digest auth . It's using the CDP and currently only supports chromium-derived browsers

**Java Example :**

```
Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

((HasAuthentication) driver).register(UsernameAndPassword.of("username", "pass"));

driver.get("http://sitewithauth");
```

**Note :** In Alpha-7 there is **bug** where it send username for both user/password. Need to wait for next release of selenium version as fix is available in trunk https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/4917444886ba16a033a81a2a9676c9267c472894

Answer (score 2):

If you have to deal with NTLM proxy authentication a good alternative is to use a configure a local proxy using [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/).

The credentials and domain are configured in `/etc/cntlm.conf`.

Afterwards you can just use you own proxy that handles all the NTLM stuff.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:3128");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: As I have read CNTLM does not work with HTTPS. This makes it completely usless for me. https://sourceforge.net/p/cntlm/support-requests/14. Apart from that CNTLM is a dead project. Bugreports have no answers since 2012.