# How to handle Windows authentication dialogue using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, autoit

I have requirement of opening share point URL and it looks for credential through windows authentication. So I read some where to use AutoIt with seleniun webdriver but how we can call this AutoIt script because my web driver script will wait until window dialogue is get off. So cursor will not go to next line to execute AutoIT script and finally we will not be able run our script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium Webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: No, whatever link you have given that is different than my question. I mean how to call AutoIt exe in selenium webdriver script when code is waiting for poppup entry to proceed further line of script.

Comment: If that is EXE then it could be only window application and selenium web driver is only for web applications..

Comment: This looks like a good enough tutorial for using AutoIT in selenium 
http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using Java or C#. In C#, I would go with MSUIA. Write a method to deal with the Windows dialogues and run it on a separate thread. This method should act as a listener to the Desktop tree and whenever encounters a control that it needs to work on, does its job. Have the method scan the Desktop tree once every 5 seconds or so and put it to sleep if no object is found.

In Java, using AutoIt should do the trick, not that it won't in C#
http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/