# A "Basic Authentication" popup appears several times using Selenium

Tags: ruby, authentication, selenium, webdriver, cucumber

I am using Selenium with Ruby. I have to switch between pages that require authentication.
Initially I push username and password with the url.

```
http://username:password@site.com/page
```

However, after couple steps, when I am redirected to another page, there is still authentication popup again.

How would I pass username/password again?

Answer (score 4):

The **authenticateUsing()** method is still currently in beta but I think it will be part of Selenium 3.0, when its finally released. From [Prashanth Sams's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver):

> The Alert Method, authenticateUsing() lets you skip the Http Basic
>   Authentication box.
>
> ```
> WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
> Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
> alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("USERNAME", "PASSWORD"));
> ```

Comment: this one looks like Java to me

Comment: I believe a Ruby version of Selenium is available and appears to be up to date with the latest version of Selenium (not Watir) :  https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings  .   The code would be similar to the Java method.