# How to do the basic http authentication using selenium web driver using Java

Tags: java, http, selenium-webdriver

I tried the following way to do the basic http authentication but it did not worked for me.

```
 FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
 profile.setPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
 driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

After this I passed the user name and password with the below approach.

```
 driver.get("https://username:password@<<URL>>");
```

If there is any special character in the password how to pass it in the URL.

Is there any generic solution which will solve this problem on all the browsers.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25945253/2798955

Answer (score 1):

No, as per knowledge i don't think there a generic way for all browsers.
Now for your problem, try mentioned below.

Since your an HTTP proxy, please verify if you have enabled "browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled" option to True.

To do so, type about:config in Firefox.
Search for browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled, double click it.

See if that helps.