# How to handle authentication pop up in selenium Webdriver when login username contains backward slash?

Tags: selenium, automation

I know there is already a question on handling pop up authentication in selenium web Driver, but in my framework the login credential is like "domain\username" so when i write down my URL:

obj.get(https://domain\Username:password@Example.com);

It gives error for "domain\Username" that "\" is not allowed.

Also my Password contains special character "@", Will it face any error??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: Put the exact error.. Try giving "\\" instead of "\"