# Unable to handle the 'File may be harmful for your computer' pop up with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

While download a .ini file I got the propmpt of keep/discard and then switched to chrome downloads page and clicked keep using selenium but after that Latest chrome versions gives a pop up with title 'Recover malware' with body keep/cancel  for this pop up no actions or sendkeys are working neither the elements on this can be inspected by inspector.

Answer (score 0):

> Click Start / Control Panel / Internet Options Click Security tab.
>
> Click Local Intranet Click Sites button.
>
> Click Advanced button.
>
> Enter the IP Address of the other machine or server (wildcards are allowed)
>
> and click Add Click Close, then OK, then OK again.

refer:-
https://superuser.com/questions/149056/disable-these-files-might-be-harmful-to-your-computer-warning

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: rather than handling the above manually I want to handle this through code.

Comment: https://chinnu9999.wordpress.com/2015/06/18/how-to-handle-windows-security-popups-using-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java