# How to pass authorization on secure server

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, https

I need to login on secured (`https`) server that requires applying certificates to complete authorization as I get certificate confirmation pop-up (`IE`) or `Secure Connection Failed` page (`Firefox`) when trying to use `driver.get(url)`.

I can use `driver.switch_to_alert().accept()` to confirm certificate usage on `IE`, but I want to avoid this pop-up appearence.
For `Firefox`, I guess, there should be appropriate preferences in `FirefoxProfile`, but I can't find exact

So how to automate process of applying certificates and user key with `selenium-webdriver`? Target browser is `IE`or `Firefox`

Comment: please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: @rajNishKuMar, Thanks, but, I'm afraid, these are different issues

Comment: oh sorry for that can u please attach a snap of the applying certificates that you are getting if possible it will give a better idea try this may be it helps  FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
Webdriver  driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);

Comment: @rajNishKuMar, thanks again for trying to help, but I use `Python` and your code seem to be on `Java` :)

Comment: @ Andersson sorry i have no idea about python