# How to handle login pop up window using Selenium WebDriver Java? Is there a way to inspect pop up using firebug

Tags: selenium-webdriver, popup

1. I am using eclipse JAVA.
2. When I execute the below code:

   ```
   public class dbscbg {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("http://ip/link");                                             
   }
   ```

   Authentication pop is seen.
3. How to handle this?
4. Is there a way to inspect pop up using firebug?
5. Looked up stackoverflow with the same query but did not understand how can pass username and password via URL.
6. Tried below piece of code. Does not work for me.
   `driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("fsdf");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Answer (score 0):

Hi please do it like below

```
 // waiting till alert is visible
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
    Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
or 
// alert is already present
Alert alt = driver.switchTo().alert();

if password authentication is necessary then     
alt.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(uid, pwd));
```

Also for more info please visit http://learn-automation.com/handle-windows-authentication-using-selenium-webdriver/

**UPDATE**

if above is not working then please try like below it will work for sure.I have used java robot class

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

     driver.get("https://www.engprod-charter.net/");
     Robot rb = new Robot();

     //Enter user name by ctrl-v
     StringSelection username = new StringSelection("username");
     Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(username, null);            
     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

     //tab to password entry field
     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
     Thread.sleep(2000);

     //Enter password by ctrl-v
     StringSelection pwd = new StringSelection("password");
     Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(pwd, null);
     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

     //press enter
     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Alert cannot be resolved to a type
 UserAndPassword cannot be resolved to a type

 at dbscbg.dbscbg.main(dbscbg.java:15)

Comment: It still throws the same error. Should I import any package for alert?

Comment: Below is my code:
package dbscbg;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class dbscbg {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("http://gehfjklja");
 
 //For authentication   
 
 Alert alt = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alt.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("gfdjfgsj", "jfhgd"));
 
 
 }

}

Comment: are you using latest version of selenium or not ? latest is 2.53

Comment: This issue i am facing is in Selenium WEBDRIVER. I am using Java EE IDE for coding.