# Getting a Authentication PopUp during application Launch

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

My script is getting failed during execution of my ruby script in water web-driver during firefox launch. The reason is that a authentication popup is getting show during the launch and the default URL will launched due to the policy set by the company & it can't be modified. So the script fails saying that not able to obtain a stable connection. Is there is any way to handle this in code as nothing can be changed from the policy side of my company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if AutoAuth works manually, and if so you can add it to your custom Firefox profile: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35918342/4072371

Code for Watir:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.add_extension "../path/to/autoauth.xpi"
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

Comment: The code have worked as expected and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If Titus's answer does not work, you might have to look into some way around that policy.. like running from a VM that is not part of your domain and not subject to policy enforcement.    You could also try downloading a slightly different version of firefox, like maybe the ESR release, directly from mozilla, which might not have that policy set.