# Dismiss Authentication Prompt in FireFox

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, authentication, firefox

I am trying to run selenium automation on a 3rd party website.

Selenium fails when firefox authentication prompt like this appears:

[image]

Works like the *Display Image* button [here](http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/#showExample10)

Is there any way to dismiss this using javascript, as part of a firefox extension or otherwise?

We have tried dismissing the prompt in selenium with the following:

`Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.dismiss();`

We have also tried disabling javascript although this solution doesn't work as we also require javascript to be enabled for our automation.

There seems to be a possible solution, as there is an [extension that can handle this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autoauth/), we are unable to use this as we can't use 3rd party code and we would like slightly different behaviour.

**Edit**: different to linked question as we are looking for a in-browser solution using javascript

Any help or guidance is appreciated,

Liam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: Did you try this format `http://username:password@URL.com`

Comment: @ChandraShekhar In our scenario we don't actually want to authenticate. We just want to dismiss the prompt, the issue is we are unable to query when the prompt appears

Comment: Can you please provide any alternate link which will pop up the same way? [To check for solution]

Comment: http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/#showExample10 The display image button, added it to the question too :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with your inputs, Alert can be dismissed only after getting the alert text. Please try this working code

```
driver.get("http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/#showExample10");

     // open URL
     driver.findElement(By.id("displayImage")).click();
     Thread.sleep(2000);
     driver.switchTo().alert();

     Alert promptAlert  = driver.switchTo().alert();
     String alertText = promptAlert .getText();
     System.out.println("Alert text is " + alertText);
     promptAlert.dismiss();
```

Comment: Hey @Chandra, this isn't working for us. Would you mind clarifying what version of selenium and firefox you are using? Thanks again :)

Comment: Selenium 2.53.0 and Firefox 47 . I tried also Chrome Driver 53

Comment: unfortunately we are not able to update from Selenium 2.46 and this solution does not work

Comment: Let me try using Selenium 2.46 and Firefox 47

Comment: Please update Firefox V>48 and Selenium >2.53.0
 or 
use Chrome browser and Selenium 2.46