# Ruby Selenium 3.0 - how to click on 'rel Attribute'?

Tags: ruby, selenium

How can I click on the login button ?

```
<a href="/bin/ids/login.smp.html?_=nc" rel="IDS_login">Login</a>
```

Below the code in the screenshot:

[image]

I can do it by xpath, but I wonder if there is other ways ?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can do it by xpath, but I wonder if there is other ways ?

I would suggest you, try using `cssSelector` which would be much faster than `xpath` to locate an element as :-

```
driver.find_element(:css, "div#anonymous > a[rel='IDS_login']").click
```

You can also locate this element using `link_text` as :-

```
driver.find_element(:link_text, "Login").click
```

Comment: Saurabh Gaur, nice thanks! can you please have a look on other ruby Selenium question :) `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076112/how-to-handle-firefox-chrome-login-pop-up-window-using-ruby-selenium-3-0-webdriv`, I'm pretty new at this..