# Exception: waiting for alert to be present

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to open a site that contain authentication alert.
To handle that alert I tried following code but no success:

```
try {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
     alert.authenticateUsing((Credentials) new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "pass"));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Alert not found");
}
```

Exception occur is:

```
Expected condition failed: waiting for alert to be present (tried for 100 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please have a look at this to see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: This is not an​ Alert. This is a pop-up which needs to be controlled through your code. Can you consider to show us your work & relevant HTML DOM please? Thanks

Comment: This is a browser authentication. It has no HTML

Comment: This is not an alert window. you will have to use AutoIT to handle this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Browser Authentication? If you are so sure why are you trying to handle through `Alert` class? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication is not a popup and we can use AutoIT or Sikuli to automate this. But this is tedious task and fortunately we are having another simple solution. The idea is to pass the username and password along with the url.

For Eg.., to pass the username and password, the URL would be **http://username:password@url**

Selenium Java code:

```
driver.get("http://USERNMAE:PASSWORD@YOUR_URL");
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.