# How to click on Cancel button on Authentication required pop up in chrome using selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click on cancel button in Chrome Authentication pop up window i've used

```
Robot rn = new robot();
rn.KeyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
rn.KeyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
rn.KeyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Enter);
```

It is not at all working,Please help how to click on Cancel button on Chrome Authentication pop up using selenium.

Comment: I am afraid you cannot achieve this..

Comment: So what to do now?

Comment: Depends on what do you want to achieve see this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java