# Handling Authentication Required pop up

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-authentication

Can please some one help me in handling window authentication pop up in chrome using selenium and C# without using AutoIT?

Window Authentication Pop up

[image: Window Authentication Pop up]

P.S. - Embedding the url with username and password (http://username:password@url/) is not working in my code. Somehow the CSS does not get load.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `driver.get("http://10.127.127.76:6162");` go for `driver.get("http://username:password@10.127.127.76:6162");`

Replace username and password with your credentials in the given solution.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: It appears that this no longer works in the latest version of Chrome. Not sure about FF or IE.