# Login at web prompt - Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to map the elements of the prompt because it is not possible to inspect them to get the ID or name of the login and password fields, I'm trying to code the code below, give a tab in the elements and even without success.

How do I automate login on this interface?

```
    driver.get("url");
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_TAB);
```

[image: login]

Comment: Why is it impossible to inspect the elements?

Comment: @BillHileman Nothing happens when I press F12, in chrome, or CTRL + U, to display the source code.

Therefore, I can not inspect the elements of the page.

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing.  I take it you can't share the URL?  Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Also, have you tried using getPageSource?

Comment: @BillHileman 
I tried it in other browsers and the result is the same, I also used the String command pageSource = driver.getPageSource (); it's nothing.

the URL is as follows: http://sharepoint.infoserver.com.br/

Comment: That's not a regular alert.  In fact, it might not even be part of the browser, it is likely part of the operating system, and I don't know that it can be automated in any way.  You may have to manually log-in before you start your automation script(s), or this simply may not be capable of being automated at all.  Sorry I wasn't able to be more help.

Comment: Paulo, Bill is correct that selenium will not be able to interact with this type of login. You can look here for other solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47005817/logging-in-using-javascript-and-selenium-webdriver-chrome

Comment: This approach currently does not work in Google Chrome. In Firefox OK.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a basic authentication popup. You can resolve it by passing the credentials in the URL itself as below:

`driver.get("http://<username>:<password>@www.example.com");`