# How to handle basic browser authentication using Selenium WebDriver Java?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, selenium-webdriver, basic-authentication

Using Selenium Webdriver with Java, I can open a URL with basic auth using driver.get("http://User:Pass@URL"). But for a webpage URL1/page1 which loads URL2/page2 inside iframe, it again asks for URL2 basic auth.

Please spare AutoIt solution. Java Robot class solution also does not solve the problem as it starts typing the credentials on whatever application is open.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: No. If you read the problem carefully, you will get to know.

Comment: Thanks. I read the problem carefully.

Comment: Please add code samle of the iframe and your attempt.