# Alert Popup in New window

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How can I fill Username and Password fields in alert? When I click a link, another window opens with alert authentication. I'm not able to switch to the alert. I get Timeout Exceptions. I used this code:

```
// two windows on browser
Set<String> window = driver.getwindowhandles();    
Iterator index = window.ierator();
String Parentwindow = index.next();
String Childwindow = index.next();

driver.switchto().window(Childwindow);

// popup on child window    
Alert alert = driver.switchto().alert();
alert.sendkeys("username");    
alert.sendkeys("password");
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered before. Selenium has a built in functionality to work with authentication popups.

Using an implicit `Wait` (this `Wait` waits until the time runs out for the given condition to become `true`) you can access the `Alert` and pass the login-credentials by using `authenticateUsing()`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(username, password));
```

An alternative way would be to provide username and password directly when accessing the URL, which bypasses the `Alert` entirely:

`driver.get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");`

Please refer to this question: [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22763968)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, too @zmag. I was already typing the other comment.