# How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver, popup

I am trying to handle authentication popup through my selenium test by passing username and password in URL.

I have tried following solutions:

1. I have tried to send username and password in URL
2. I have tried handling with alert, it doesn't work.
3. I have tried solutions provided in - [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java), almost all other than AutoIT, none of them worked for me

I have a Maven project, I am trying to send url with username and password from project.properties file, which looks like this -

URL = https://username:password@URL

open url code-

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.navigate.to(URL);

I get below error in browser console:
"there has been a problem with your fetch operation: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials"

Comment: I see there is a problem in the URL
URL = https//username:password@URL
It should have been URL = https://username:password@URL
You are missing ":" after https

Comment: @Raghavendra Bankapur,  I missed it while posting the question, I have ":" in URL in my code. Thank you

Comment: If it is a public website, can you please paste the complete URL here?

Comment: @Raghavendra Bankapur, it is not public website. I was able to resolve the issue using AutoIT script. Thank you for the help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to handle this using AutoIT script. 
The script looks something like this,

WinWaitActive("Sign in")

Sleep(5000)

Send("username")

Send("{TAB}")

Send("password")

Send("{ENTER}")

I run this script through my code,

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("(path)\AutoIt\script.exe");

driver.get(prop.getProperty(URL));

driver.navigate().refresh();