# how to pass windows credentials in Url using Selenium in https

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I tried using:

1. https://username:password@xyz.com
2. Using Alerts in Selenium.
3. Using Auto IT.

but nothing works for me.

AutoIT sometimes works and sometimes fails so it seems to be not reliable.

can anyone help with the same?

Comment: duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: I am looking for https and it is not an alert @stacktome