# Selenium - C# - Chrome - Your connection to this site is not private pop up

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, automation

I get the below pop-up when I run my selenium tests on chrome

chrome v = Version 81.0.4044.138

[image]

I have tried the following with no luck

```
 options.AddArgument("ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
 options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
 options.AddArgument("allow-running-insecure-content");
```

Has anyone a solution to this?

Comment: Is your URL HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: I am using IIS for testing on local environment. So testing on localhost

Comment: So what?  Do you know differences between HTTP and HTTPS?  The server settings determine if HTTPS is required.  Doesn't matter if local or remote.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: Yes i tried to edit my comment but it wouldn't let me. its http

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue.  I used  http://localhost:1234 instead of http://12.3.45.67:1234/. silly mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue. I used localhost:1234 instead of 12.3.45.67:1234. silly mistake