# Unable to click the OK button in ruby watir automation

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

When I am try to click the OK button, its showing me like OK clicked and the corresponding popover is not closing.Once that popover closed after OK button clicked, then only the data saved successfully. But here that pop is not closing once OK clicked. Manualy its working.

Comment: It would help if you could share more details. What is the HTML you are working with? What is the code that you are executing?

Comment: <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="xwt_widget_form_TextButton_67_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">OK</span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what are you using watir, selenium?
better do a script from the automation motor. The below example is for watir with AutoIt (for IE)

```
au3 = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
au3.WinWaitActive("Authentication Required")
au3.Send("Domanin/userName")
au3.Send("{TAB}")
au3.Send("Pass")
au3.Send("{ENTER}")
```

for selenium would be similar. See if this other SO answer works for you. [Alert Handling + Java + webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066382/alert-handling-java-webdriver)